# Completed pods garbage collection

Tags: kubernetes

In The [Lifecycle of a Pod](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pod-states/) I read:

> In general, pods which are created do not disappear until someone
>   destroys them. This might be a human or a ReplicationController, or
>   another controller. The only exception to this rule is that pods with
>   a PodPhase of Succeeded or Failed for more than some duration
>   (determined by the master) will expire and be automatically reaped.

I create pods with RestartPolicy = Never, but after completion (status Succeeded) they do not get reaped.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

you can set --terminated-pod-gc-threshold on the controller-manager. That will kick in for phases:

> if phase := pod.Status.Phase; phase != api.PodPending && phase !=     api.PodRunning && phase != api.PodUnknown

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/podgc/gc_controller.go#L126

Comment: can the --terminated-pod-gc-threshold be set on GKE?

Answer (score 0):

> can the --terminated-pod-gc-threshold be set on GKE?

It doesn't seem it's possible to change "--terminated-pod-gc-threshold" on GKE for users:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172663707

*Given that the controller manager is managed by Google, GKE users cannot change that value.*